# center div until left margin is too narrow, then stop?

Tags: css, margin, centering

I have a `div` that's centered **horizontally**.  This is great on wide screens, but if you pull the browser window *narrower*, it moves under another `div` which is on the **left** but there's still empty space to the **right**.  I would like it to stop centering when it hits that other `div`.  Such as `margin auto` but with a `min margin` of `300px` on the **left**.

As far as I know, there's no such thing.  But is there a way to achieve this result?

Thank you.

Comment: can we see some code please?

Comment: Have you heard of media queries? You can define breakpoints, so for wide windows you can use `margin: 0 auto;` and for narrow windows you use something else.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this,use 300px as min-margin below

1. css code

   ```
   html,body {
       height: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
       margin: 0;
   }
   .left {
       width: 200px;
       height: 100%;
       background: red;
       float: left;
   }        
   .right-inner {
       width: 300px;
       height: 300px;
       background: blue;
       left: -500px; /*  -(200px+300px)  */
       position: relative;
       margin: auto
   }
   .right {
       width: calc(100% - 1000px); /* 100% - (200px+300px)*2 */
       left: 1000px; /*  (200px+300px)*2 */
       position: absolute;
   }
   ```
2. Html code

   ```
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="right">
       <div class="right-inner"></div>
   </div>
   ```

if the width of your left-part is leftWidth, and your min-margin is minMargin, the width of right element is rightWidth

- rightWidth = calc(100% - (leftWidth+minMargin)*2)
- rightLeft = (leftWidth+minMargin)*2
- rightInnerLeftOffest = -(leftWidth+minMargin)

In a word,I just use the left of an absolute element to make the minMargin,and margin:auto + position:relative to center the right-inner element.
I hope you can understand what I said, create a new html page will help your to get my point

Also media-query will help you do this thing eazy